# Getting Angular resource promise data in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, resources, promise, directive

I am trying to get ng resource data from directive but what I am getting is promise object, here is an image:

[image]

Here is my factory:

```
return {
  // get actual data from resource
  getFilterData: function (keyword) {
    console.log("filterData: " + keyword);
    return $resource('data/filterdata.json').query().$promise.then(function(results) {
      return results;
    }, function(error) { // Check for errors
    });
  }
}
```

So what I just want is to get value array.

Comment: isn't the data in the array, _value_ ?

Comment: Yes it is but I cant get like this way: scope.matchedSuggestions.$$state.value

Comment: Show us the controller

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've solved this issue, the thing was that it was returning the promise and after using then function I got the json.